# how to store PCMU/8000 audio in FLV file?

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, audio-recording, flv, streaming-flv-video

I am receiving audio with following SDP parameters from a video camera,
I want to store this audio into an FLV file. I am using annex E of this document http://download.macromedia.com/f4v/video_file_format_spec_v10_1.pdf to construct my FLV and I can play video easily.
The problem is with audio which is not playing properly and all noise is there.

In FLV AudioTagHeader my value is (1000 0011)base2.

```
v=0
o=- 1450947387868742 1450947387868742 IN IP4 10.4.163.199
s=Media Presentation
e=NONE
b=AS:5100
t=0 0
a=control:rtsp://10.4.163.199:554/Streaming/Channels/101/?transportmode=unicast&profile=Profile_1
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:5000
a=recvonly
a=x-dimensions:1280,720
a=control:rtsp://10.4.163.199:554/Streaming/Channels/101/trackID=1?transportmode=unicast&profile=Profile_1
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 profile-level-id=420029; packetization-mode=1; sprop-parameter-sets=Z00AH5pmAoAt/zUBAQFAAAD6AAAw1AE=,aO48gA==
m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 0
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:50
a=recvonly
a=control:rtsp://10.4.163.199:554/Streaming/Channels/101/track
D=2?transportmode=unicast&profile=Profile_1
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=Media_header:MEDIAINFO=494D4B48010100000400010010710110401F000000FA000000000000000000000000000000000000;
a=appversion:1.0
```

It will be great if I can get some help on it

Comment: The resultant noise was due to 0x01 byte after audioTagHeader. This byte only has to be inserted for AAC formatted audio.. not for PCMU/PCMA formatted audio.

Comment: This bug was identified using audio graphical tool.. it showed me glitches at regular intervals with 0x01 byte at all places.. audio in graphical format helped me to figure out the issue.